# PHP - Counting array elements in a specific range

Tags: php

I have an array with 950 elements. Values of elements are between 80-110. I want to count how many of them between 80-90, 90-100 and 100-110. Then I'll show them on a graph. Is this possible to count elements like that in php ?

Comment: Yes, that is definitely possible.

Comment: Can you suggest a source for it ? I couldn't find anything about it

Comment: Well, this is so basic that you won't find anything. You simply loop over the array and count the values into the three groups. You won't find every problem in a pre-cooked recipe. Perhaps a [basic PHP tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/PHP/Language_Basics/1120__PHP_Array_foreach.htm) will help?

Comment: I understand, thanks for it. It will help. I'm a beginner on php so I'm sorry if that was a silly question.

Comment: It wasn't a silly question. Everyone has to start somewhere. You'll get better with practice. Be creative.

Comment: Are you already familiar with [`foreach()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop through each element in an array? Start by initializing some counter variables to 0, loop through the array, check each value, and increment the appropriate counter.

Comment: Your question is missing a coding attempt, and proof of effort.  I am skeptical about your desired outcome -- do you really want 90 values to be counted in the lower AND middle group? And 100 counted in the middle AND upper group?  There are 31 possible values in your range, which group gets the extra one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do it by running a for loop. Create an array containing a range of elements and run a for loop. While you will run the loop on that time count the array element according to your given three groups. Finally you will get the total number of elements inside the given range. For your better help below I am giving an example :

```
<?php
    $number = array(80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110);
   $count1 = $count2 = $count3 = 0;
   for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($number); $i++) {
       if($number[$i] >= 80 && $number[$i] <= 90 ) {
           $count1++;
       }
       if($number[$i] >= 90 && $number[$i] <= 100 ) {
           $count2++;
       }
       if($number[$i] >= 100 && $number[$i] <= 110 ) {
           $count3++;
       }

   }
   echo "The number between 80-90 = ".$count1."<br>";
   echo "The number between 90-100 = ".$count2."<br>";
   echo "The number between 100-110 = ".$count3."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: This is not correct. This will always count how many numbers, for example in your first loop, are between `80` and `90`. This will always be `11` no matter what's inside `$number`. Also your array is never really used.

Comment: Why don't you use `foreach` for that? That way, your code would also work if other indices are used

Answer (score 1):

I think OP may have been going for a more *pythonic* answer (but in PHP)

```
//only valid in php 5.3 or higher

function countInRange($numbers,$lowest,$highest){
  //bounds are included, for this example
      return count(array_filter($numbers,function($number) use ($lowest,$highest){
    return ($lowest<=$number && $number <=$highest); 
    }));
}

$numbers = [1,1,1,1,2,3,-5,-8,-9,10,11,12];

echo countInRange($numbers,1,3); // echoes 6
echo countInRange($numbers,-7,3); // echoes 7
echo countInRange($numbers,19,20); //echoes 0
```

the 'use' keyword indicates a 'closure' in php. Taken for granted in other languages, for example javascript, variables in an outer function are imported scope-wise into the inner function automatically (i.e. without special keywords), the inner function may also be called a "partial function".

For some reason in PHP 5.2x or lower, variables were not imported scope-wise automatically, and in PHP 5.3 or higher, the use keyword can overcome this. The syntax is very simple:

```
$functionHandle = function(<arguments>) use (<scope-imported variables>){
    //...your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having too many comparisons jump to next loop when you have determined where your number belongs.

```
function countOccurences( array $numbersArray ):array
{
  $return = array('n80to90' => 0, 'n90to100' => 0, 'n100to110' => 0);
  foreach( $numbersArray as $number ){
    if( $number < 80 || $number > 110 )
      continue;
    if($number < 91){
      $return['n80to90']++;
      continue;
    }
    if($number < 101){
      $return['n90to100']++;
      continue;
    }
    $return['n100to110']++;
  } 
  return  $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine that your statistical graphic that would want to represent values on the cusp of two groups as belonging to both groups.  For this reason, I'll offer a condition-less function-less technique which can be execute in a foreach loop.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OMmkb))

```
$sampleData = range(80, 110);
$result = array_fill_keys(['80s', '90s', '100s'], 0);  // set 0 defaults for incrementation
foreach ($sampleData as $value) {
    ++$result[(10 * ((int)($value / 10) <=> 9) + 90) . 's'];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  '80s' => 10,
  '90s' => 10,
  '100s' => 11,
)
```

My technique manufactures the appropriate keys from the values by:

1. Dividing by 10
2. Truncating the decimal (same effect as `floor()`
3. Making a 3-way comparison via the spaceship operator (returns `-1`, `0`, or `1`)
4. Multiplying the "-1|0|1" by 10
5. Adding 90
6. And finally concatenating an "s".

The `++` means add 1 to the current value of the element with the corresponding key.

---

Alternatively, if you wanted to group the values as "90+below" (80-90), "100+below" (91-100), and "110+below" (101-110), then it is a simple matter of adjusting the key-generating factors.

Instead of counting, I'll show the elements assigned to each group.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UcZga))

```
$sampleData = range(80, 110);
foreach ($sampleData as $value) {
    $result[(10 * ((int)(($value - 1) / 10) <=> 9) + 100) . '+under'][] = $value;
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  '90+under' => 
  array (
    0 => 80,
    1 => 81,
    2 => 82,
    3 => 83,
    4 => 84,
    5 => 85,
    6 => 86,
    7 => 87,
    8 => 88,
    9 => 89,
    10 => 90,
  ),
  '100+under' => 
  array (
    0 => 91,
    1 => 92,
    2 => 93,
    3 => 94,
    4 => 95,
    5 => 96,
    6 => 97,
    7 => 98,
    8 => 99,
    9 => 100,
  ),
  '110+under' => 
  array (
    0 => 101,
    1 => 102,
    2 => 103,
    3 => 104,
    4 => 105,
    5 => 106,
    6 => 107,
    7 => 108,
    8 => 109,
    9 => 110,
  ),
)
```